PMSM - RMS phase current as a function of Id and Iq
Assuming to have a 3-phase PMSM driven with a balanced system of currents with sinusoidal shape, is there a way to write the RMS phase current as a function of Id and Iq?
I want to use the RMS phase currents for a rough estimation of losses in the inverter, in the motor windings and in the cables. I get Id and Iq from the torque and speed profile.
Looking at some experimental data I have found online, I would say \$I_{phase_{RMS}} = \frac{\sqrt(I_d^2 + I_q^2)}{\sqrt(2)}\$. However, I am very uncertain about this and would appreciate a detailed explanation.

I have no mathematical proof, but looking at input VS. output forms (source) gives the relation you mention.
d.q are quadrature components so: \$\lvert I_{peak}\rvert=\sqrt{I_d^2+I_q^2}\$
then \$\lvert I_{RMS}\rvert=\frac{\sqrt{I_d^2+I_q^2}}{\sqrt{2}}\$

